# On reading the notation $x\to \infty$

Tags: notation, infinity

Why is it better to read $x\to \infty$ as "$x$ grows without bound" rather than "$x$ approaches/comes closer to infinity"?

Comment: It is useful to think of the process as a dynamic one. The improved wording may deter some students from substituting the "object" $\infty$ into an expression, and getting numerically wrong anwers. Maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes down to the "$\infty$ is not a number" problem.

Here's one argument against saying $x$ "approaches infinity": if $x\to c$ for some number $c\in \mathbb R$, then we say that $x$ approaches $c$ in that $|x-c|\to 0$.  However, when $x\to\infty$, we can't say that $|x-\infty|\to 0$.  So, $x$ doesn't really "approach" infinity in the same sense.

Comment: Um. Okay. So here we need a way to measure distance between $x$ and $c$. But if we have just general topological space without a way to measure distance, is it still better to say "grows w.o. bound"? Or does my question even make sense in a general topological space?

Comment: In a general topological space, we might not have a notion of "distance" (that is, a metric), so (arguably) it wouldn't make sense to talk about $x$ "getting closer to" or "approaching" a value.

Comment: @curious In a general topological space you might not have anything analogous to $\infty$, either. What if it's a finite space, for example? Or what if it's a bounded metric space?

Answer (score 2):

You can pronounce it however you want -- the important thing is the *definition* being referred to. And "$x\to\infty$" *alone* doesn't even have a (commonly used and accepted) definition; only larger pieces of notation of which it is part get ones, such as $\lim_{x\to\infty} \cdots x\cdots$.

There are some formalisms where one considers "infinity" to be an actual point in a topological space that it makes excellent sense to approach. Some of these are consistent with the usual use of "$x\to\infty$" in elementary real analysis. It is often mostly up to temperament whether you use one of them or prefer to reduce everything to talking about actual numbers only.

Answer (score 1):

Because "$x$ approaches infinity" assumes the existence of an object called infinity that $x$ approaches.
While there's no big deal with in deed adding such a symbol (it's just an object with a name, not something mysteriously supernaturally big), one should still take care as $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=a$ is still *not* defined the same way $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=a$ is: There is no point in saying "For all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $|x-\infty|<\delta$ (?!) we have $|f(x)-a|<\epsilon$"